# Is there any software that can help me draw pictures or shapes in assembly language easily?

Tags: assembly, tasm

Is there any software that can help me draw pictures or shapes in assembly language easily? 
I'm using tasm 5, editing the code in notepad++ and running in cmd.
I'm using windows. 32bit.

Comment: You need to expand the question a bit. You're running from a (text-based) command-prompt, so are you looking for ASCII-art to create images in the command-window or are you trying to create a graphics canvas and write pixel data?

Comment: not the ascii, I'm inputting pixel data on the notepad++, do you know any easier technique ?

Comment: Why would you use assembly for this?  This is what higher level languages are for :)

Comment: School project. They still teach this on my school. If I have another option, I would take other programming language. T_T

Answer (score 0):

I think there's really no easy way in creating this. So I've figured using PS's grid on counting the pixels. and just made a batch file, so that I wouldn't type those tasms and tlinks anymore. I've resized the windows and now there are 3 windows on my screen. hehe

update: alternative on counting the pixel is using icofx or gamemaker